# How to generate and print executive summary after running scripts in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I have a keyword driven framework in UFT. List of scripts listed in an excel file. Driver script simply executes one script at a time. After the test run, I get this executive summary from UFT.

[image]

How can I customize the executive summary so I can see the more information on the summary like steps details, which steps passed, failed, etc.? Also how can I print the executive summary?

Answer (score 0):

*I have a keyword driven framework in UFT. List of scripts listed in an excel file.*

Most likely, you are using only one Action in your test suite, you are seeing only 1 test execution report. This is a general drawback of having Excel driven keyword framework. What you need to do is to create your own custom test script start/stop markers and then generate a report (preferably by using a custom XSL).

Sample test result

[image]

Notice that in the sample result, the tests are anything which starts with *▬▬ UC_*. I've further divided each tests into various parts grouped under *●●● TD_*. You then have to read the UFT generated results.xml and convert it into meaningful result. For example, I converted it into an Excel file.

[image]